# Unity Compute shader fails to compile when setting RWStructuredBuffer value

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I am currently trying to convert my marching cubes algorithm from c# to a compute shader. It seems the problem is occurring on the last two lines. I've reported the bug as the unity error log says but, I was wondering is there away to code around the error and store the result (floar3[15] and an int[15])?

**Error Message**

> Shader compiler: Compile marchingCubes.compute - getVertices: Internal error communicating with the shader compiler process.  Please report a bug including this shader and the editor log.

**HLSL script**

```
int edgeTable[256] = { 0x0  , 0x109, 0x203, ..., 0x203, 0x109, 0x0};

int triTableLengths[256] ={0,3,3, ... ,3,3,0};

int triTable[256][15] =
{
    {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
    .... other tri tables
};

float3 points[12] =
{
    float3(0.5, 0, 0),
    float3(1, 0, 0.5),
    float3(0.5, 0, 1),
    float3(0, 0, 0.5),

    float3(0.5, 1, 0),
    float3(1, 1, 0.5),
    float3(0.5, 1, 1),
    float3(0, 1, 0.5),

    float3(0, 0.5, 0),
    float3(1, 0.5, 0),
    float3(1, 0.5, 1),
    float3(0, 0.5, 1)
};

struct cubeResult
{
    float3 vertices[15];
    int triangles[15];
};

RWStructuredBuffer<cubeResult> Result;

float nodes[10][10][10];
float threshold;
float3 distPerNode = float3(1, 1, 1);

float lerp1(float x1, float x2, float t)
{
    return (t - x1) / (x2 - x1);
}

[numthreads(10, 10, 10)]
void getVertices(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    if (id.x + 1 == 100 || id.y + 1 == 100 || id.z + 1 == 100)
    {
        return;
    }

    int index = 0;
    //Texture2D temp = nodes[id.z + 1];
    float verticesTemp[8] = 
    {
        nodes[id.x][id.y + 1][id.z + 1],
        nodes[id.x + 1][id.y + 1][id.z + 1],
        nodes[id.x + 1][id.y + 1][id.z],
        nodes[id.x][id.y + 1][id.z],

        nodes[id.x][id.y][id.z + 1],
        nodes[id.x + 1][id.y][id.z + 1],
        nodes[id.x + 1][id.y][id.z],
        nodes[id.x][id.y][id.z]
    };

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 8; i1++)
    {
        if (verticesTemp[i1] > threshold)
        {
            index = index + pow(2, i1);
        }
    }

    int triangles[15] = triTable[index];

    float3 vertices[15];

    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < triTableLengths[index]; i2++)
    {
        vertices[i2] = points[triangles[i2]];
        
        if (vertices[i2].x == 0.5)
        {
            vertices[i2].x = lerp1(
                nodes[id.x - id.x % 2][id.y][id.z],
                nodes[id.x + 1 - id.x % 2][id.y][id.z],
                threshold);
        }
        if (vertices[i2].y == 0.5)
        {
            vertices[i2].y = lerp1(
                nodes[id.x][id.y - id.x % 2][id.z],
                nodes[id.x][id.y + 1 - id.x % 2][id.z],
                threshold);
        }
        if (vertices[i2].z == 0.5)
        {
            vertices[i2].z = lerp1(
                nodes[id.x][id.y][id.z - id.x % 2],
                nodes[id.x][id.y][id.z + 1 - id.x % 2],
                threshold);
        }

        vertices[i2].x = (vertices[i2].x + id.x) * distPerNode.x;
        vertices[i2].y = (vertices[i2].y + id.y) * distPerNode.y;
        vertices[i2].z = (vertices[i2].z + id.z) * distPerNode.z;

    }
    
    Result[id.x + id.y * 10 + id.z * 100].vertices = vertices;
    Result[id.x + id.y * 10 + id.z * 100].triangles = triangles;
}
```

**The lines that causes the error**

```
    Result[id.x + id.y * 10 + id.z * 100].vertices = vertices;
    Result[id.x + id.y * 10 + id.z * 100].triangles = triangles;
```